# Remove login on the checkout if the email is already registered

Tags: magento2, checkout

Currently at the checkout, if you enter an email that has already been registered in the system, Magento ask you to enter your password.

This is a problem because many customers don't remember their passwords.

How could I remove this login from the checkout? (i.e even if the email has been used before, allow to checkout normally without needing to log in)

Comment: In Magento 2, if the email has been registered, you are asked to log in, but not forced to log in.

Comment: I understand. But it confuses costumers. I would really like Magento to not ask at all.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override **`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js`** file in your theme and force **`self.isPasswordVisible(false);`**.

Around line 58, you will find the code like below:

```
/**
 * Callback on changing email property
 */
emailHasChanged: function () {
    var self = this;

    clearTimeout(this.emailCheckTimeout);

    if (self.validateEmail()) {
        quote.guestEmail = self.email();
        checkoutData.setValidatedEmailValue(self.email());
    }
    this.emailCheckTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if (self.validateEmail()) {
            self.checkEmailAvailability();
        } else {
            self.isPasswordVisible(false);
        }
    }, self.checkDelay);

    checkoutData.setInputFieldEmailValue(self.email());
},
```

You need to change it like below code:

```
/**
 * Callback on changing email property
 */
emailHasChanged: function () {
    var self = this;

    clearTimeout(this.emailCheckTimeout);

    if (self.validateEmail()) {
        quote.guestEmail = self.email();
        checkoutData.setValidatedEmailValue(self.email());
    }


    // this.emailCheckTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
    //     if (self.validateEmail()) {
    //         self.checkEmailAvailability();
    //     } else {
    //         self.isPasswordVisible(false);
    //     }
    // }, self.checkDelay);
    self.isPasswordVisible(false);

    checkoutData.setInputFieldEmailValue(self.email());
},
```